# How can I create normal maps for my model without generating it from a model or texture?

Tags: texturing, shaders, workflow, normal-map, height-map

I want to add detail to my model, which isn't present in the model or texture. Something to add detail to the face. My textures are flat shaded, so they wont be very helpful in generating anything, and the model is just a rounded sphere.

My texture is something like this:

[image]

And I want to create something like this, to add minor face details like mouth / eyes, without them being in the model.

[image]

Are there any methods to create this either in blender or another program?

Comment: Yes. Blender has Bake a Normal Map. Search for tutorials on Blender Bake Normal Map.  This site or the site that has the name that rhymes with NooNube.  Look on the right side of this web page.

Comment: Mesh Models and Textures are common place ways of representing data, thus part of your title to the question seems like you are trying to escape a common practice.  I would like to see others comment on this.  Now is the time to use an accepted practice.

Comment: You may want to see displacement modifier ... with a texture.